# How to display formatted large JSON file in browser or application?

Tags: json, plugins

I have so far used Jsonview chrome extension to view formatted json. Now i have to work with large JSON file (3MB) and it crashes chrome.

What app or browser extension, plugin .. do you recommend for viewing large json files?

Comment: jsbeautifier.org survives, jsonlint dies.. If you make an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)  this will also debug your code..

or use [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to preview the file to understand the general structure and data without necessarily seeing the entire file, you could use Cluria (http://www.cluria.com). I've tested it on JSON files of more than 100MB in size and it loads incredibly fast.

Its entirely free and web-based so no downloads needed.

Disclaimer: I created the Cluria website.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa) for Chrome. Although I'm not sure whether it can handle large amounts of data, but at least it's worth of trying.